# Caddy error on https://127.0.0.1/ or sub1.localhost

Tags: https, localhost, reverse-proxy

So, I have this `Caddyfile`

```
{
    local_certs
    debug
}

* {
    respond "Hello, Default! {host}"
}
```

and this `docker-compose.yml`

```yml
version: "3.7"

services:
  caddy:
    image: caddy
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./Caddyfile:/etc/caddy/Caddyfile:ro
```

I get an SSL Handshake error (not cert error) when trying to open `https://sub1.localhost/` or `https://127.0.0.1/` (the `-k` is to ignore cert errors):

```
> curl -i -k "https://localhost/"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Alt-Svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Server: Caddy
Date: Sat, 02 Mar 2024 14:46:19 GMT
Content-Length: 25

Hello, Default! localhost

> curl -i -k "https://sub1.localhost/"
curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_ILLEGAL_MESSAGE (0x80090326) - This error usually occurs when a fatal SSL/TLS alert is received (e.g. handshake failed). More detail may be available in the Windows System event log.

> curl -i -k "https://127.0.0.1/"
curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_ILLEGAL_MESSAGE (0x80090326) - This error usually occurs when a fatal SSL/TLS alert is received (e.g. handshake failed). More detail may be available in the Windows System event log.
```

The Log says `http: TLS handshake error from 172.22.0.1:44886: no certificate available for 'sub1.localhost'`

Why?

https://caddyserver.com/docs/automatic-https#overview even has `127.0.0.1` and `localhost` as an example that Caddy should serve via a locally created certificate.

Isn't Caddy supposed to serve that via a self generated cert?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are testing with Curl, **SNI** could be an issue here. Try with the `--resolve` option as explained here: https://caddy.community/t/why-curl-fails-while-browser-calls-succeed/9841/2

And since it appears that you have not provisioned `sub1.localhost` in your Caddy file, you should implement [On-Demand TLS](https://caddyserver.com/docs/automatic-https#on-demand-tls) if you expect Caddy to generate the certificate dynamically. Have a look here for a tutorial: [Serving tens of thousands of domains over HTTPS with Caddy](https://caddy.community/t/serving-tens-of-thousands-of-domains-over-https-with-caddy/11179)

But for `localhost` you will probably want something like this instead (untested):

```
https:// {
    tls internal {
        on_demand
    }
}
```

Be sure to check the Caddy **logs** to troubleshoot.